# Compare Two Date (mm/yyyy) strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Okay, I have an issue I cannot quiet figure out and need some help. My clients offers payment plans and if often stuck with CC that expire before their payment plan. I need a way to identify those people for my client so they can actively contact them but I am having issues in comparing the two varchar columns as in I get false positives because it's a varchar.

```
SELECT        
    RegID, EventID, PlayerID, AgeGroup, OrderDate, paymentDate, expDate, 
    CASE 
       WHEN LEN(CAST(DATEPART(month, DATEADD(mm, paymentTerm - 1, paymentDate)) AS varchar)) = 1 
          THEN '0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, DATEADD(mm, paymentTerm - 1, paymentDate)) AS varchar) 
          ELSE CAST(DATEPART(month, DATEADD(mm, paymentTerm - 1, paymentDate)) AS varchar) 
    END + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(year, DATEADD(mm, paymentTerm - 1, paymentDate)) AS varchar) AS lastPaymentCheck, 
    profileID, 
    DATEADD(mm, paymentTerm - 1, paymentDate) AS lastPaymentDate, paymentTerm,
    CASE 
       WHEN 
          CASE 
             WHEN LEN(CAST(DATEPART(month, DATEADD(mm, paymentTerm - 1, paymentDate)) AS varchar)) = 1 
                THEN '0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, DATEADD(mm, paymentTerm - 1, paymentDate)) AS varchar) 
                ELSE CAST(DATEPART(month, DATEADD(mm, paymentTerm - 1, paymentDate)) AS varchar) 
          END + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(year, DATEADD(mm, paymentTerm - 1, paymentDate)) AS varchar) > expDate 
          THEN 'Bad' ELSE 'Good' END AS lastPaymentCheckResult
```

I am creating a field from the first payment date to get the end payment date (lastPaymentCheck).  I need to compare that formatted field (MM/YYYY) to the expDate (MM/YYYY) field.  Data Examples of what I am getting:

```
expDate   lastPaymentCheck   lastPaymentCheckResult
------------------------------------------------------
02/2021   05/2008            BAD (Should be Good)
10/2019   11/2017            BAD (Should be Good)
01/2018   05/2018            Bad (Correct)
06/2019   05/2018            Good (Correct
```

I understand why this is happening because it's a varchar column, I need help to correct this to what it should do. Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really store the dates in the database as *dates*.  But if you are going to use strings, they should by in YYYYMM format.

They are easily enough converted to this format.  So this should do what you want:

```
select (case when right(expDate, 4) + left(expDate, 2) <= right(lastPaymentCheck, 4) + left(lastPaymentCheck, 2)
             then 'Good' else 'Bad'
        end) as lastPaymentCheckResult
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I will try that and let you know.

Comment: If it's yyyyMM then store as a number...otherwise use a date